# Social sign in while using mobile applications

Tags: mobile, social-media

The use of social sign on buttons to get people to log into web based applications is pretty common and has become quite a norm but I am wondering if the same logic could be extended to mobile applications instead of requiring the user the sign up using an email address and password.

One of the concerns/constraints I can think about is the need to share information between the facebook app (lets assume Facebook is the social sign on method used here) but I am just curious to know why it really hasnt caught on as a one click login process in mobiles would be so useful.

Comment: Are you talking about native mobile apps?

Comment: Yes,I was referring to native mobile apps

Comment: There's no definitive answer here from the UX perspective as there's coding involved (the reason could be in the integration troubles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is widely used, both in native and browser-based apps.** But the nuances are more on the coding side of things.

See a very visual list of [iOS apps' login screens](http://pttrns.com/logins), lots of them with facebook or twitter integration (or both).

Android has very tight integration with Google's Oauth by default, and [all kind of sync connections](https://secure.relien.com/images/andriod/android2.png) can be established (Twitter, Facebook, Whatsapp, etc.) Also iOS recently integrated [Twitter to their OS](http://blog.twitter.com/2011/06/ios-5-tweet-everywhere.html).

Another example: the StackExchange sites have the same Oauth login options available in the mobile version.